# dismiss keyboard without touch gesture recognizer

Tags: ios, swift

I have a view that has two textfields in the top of the view and a tableview in the bottom half. If I add a touch gesture recognizer to the view, table row selection no longer works. One of the textfields uses the default keyboards, but the other uses a decimal pad. I could use return or "Done" in its place for the first textview, but the decimal pad doesn't have that option.

I have solved the problem by adding a "Dismiss Keyboard" button to the view, but it feels ugly to me. Is there another way?

Comment: you can always add a toolbar to your keyboard with a dismiss option; it is not ugly; or you can change your base `UIView` to `UIController` and can handle the touch-down event and resign the first responser.

Comment: This sounds like a UXUI question and deserves screenshots.  It's not a Stack Overflow question.

Comment: It's quite fine for stack. Let's help Paul instead of telling him where to go.

Comment: only add the gesture when the keyboard is displayed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve this problem is, convert the root view (which is the superview of the two textfields and the tableview) to a `UIControl`.
Then add a `touchDown` or a `touchUpInside` event handler to the control, which will dismiss the keyboard.

I much prefer using UIControl over UIGestureRecognizer to solve such problems because it handles events elegantly and obeys hierarchy, so for instance, if a UITableView is its subview, the UIControl will not interfere with scroll and touch events on the UITableView.

**Addendum:**

You can also add a custom view as a `inputAccessoryView` of the textfields which can in turn contain a keyboard dismissal button. This view will not be a part of your view hierarchy, but, as the name suggests, will be an accessory view of your keyboard. It could, for instance, have an 'X' button to dismiss the keyboard.

The way to use input accessory view is:

```
    // this needs to be an instance variable
    self.kbAccessoryView = UIView() //add button, add action etc.
    self.firstTextfield.inputAccessoryView = kbAccessoryView
    self.secondTextfield.inputAccessoryView = kbAccessoryView
```

Comment: Great solution, and easy to implement!

Answer (score 1):

you can simply dismiss keyboard with one line of code

```
self.view.endEditing(true)
```

check this out also [TPKeyboardAvoiding](https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a 'Dismiss' or 'Done' button to such keyboards by using this link: https://github.com/chrisamanse/iOS-KeyboardAccessoryToolbar/tree/master/KeyboardAccessoryToolbar